# Only load javascript file on wide screen size?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I can load a javaScript file only when the screen size is wider than 1000px.

If I was in the javaScript file, and wanted to do something, I would simply do this...

```
function example(){
  if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
    //do something here....
  }
}
```

...however I want to call the whole JS file when wide enough.

So the logic will be something like this at the bottom of my HTML file...

```
If page is wide enough...
   <script src="path/to/file"></script>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to load _any_ javascript if the page width is less than 1000px?

Comment: no there will be some javaScript already, just not this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), like so:

```
$.getScript('script.js', function(){  
  // here the code in script.js is available
});
```

and for the resize

```
$(window).resize(function() {});
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly...

if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
  $.getScript("path/to/file");
}